# Thread Execution Timing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written a program which depends on threads heavily.  In addition, there is a requirement to measure the total time taken by each thread, and also the execution time (kernel time plus user time).

There can be an arbitrary number of threads and many may run at once.  This is down to user activity.  I need them to run as quickly as possible, so using something which has some overhead like WMI/Performance Monitor to measure thread times is not ideal.

At the moment, I'm using GetThreadTimes, as shown in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ExecutionStopwatch.aspx

My question is simple: I understand .NET threads may not correspond on a one-to-one basis with system threads (though in all my testing so far, it seems to have been one to one).  That being the case, if .NET decides to put two or more of my threads into one system thread, am I going to get strange results from my timing code?  If so (or even if not), is there another way to measure the kernel and user time of a .NET thread?

Comment: Personally I would go for a thread pool like [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx) and use their performance counters to measure things.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question or rather what you actually want to measure and why. Have you considered using the Stopwatch type + logging for just simple timings or any regular CPU profiler, such as ANTS or Jetbrain's?

Answer (score 1):

as it stated: Multithreading is managed internally by a thread scheduler, a function the CLR typically delegates to the operating system. A thread scheduler ensures all active threads are allocated appropriate execution time, and that threads that are waiting or blocked (for instance, on an exclusive lock or on user input)  do not consume CPU time.
  Theoretically NET team may implement their own scheduler, but i doubt this.So i think the GetThreadTimes function is what you need.